# Insert HTML markup using Meteor

Tags: html, templates, meteor, markup

How can I display marked up string data in a Meteor template?

I need to display a string from my database that contains some basic HTML tags such that the resulting text is properly formatted.  It currently just displays the markup text.

Here's the relevant part of the template:

```
<span class="description">{{description}}</span>
```

Where {{description}} is the string containing markup (like "hello<br>world").

I'd like it to display

```
hello
world
```

rather than

```
hello<br>world
```

I guess this would be similar to using innerHTML in javascript.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To override HTML-escape in Handlebars, use the triple-stash:

```
<span class="description">{{{description}}}</span>
```

Comment: Note that you also need triple braces if you are using a markdown package, otherwise your markdown is converted to HTML but then escaped. {{#markdown}}{{{description}}}{{/markdown}}

Comment: That's really cool ! Is there another purpose to those triple handlebars ?